# How to setup Amazon Polly SDK with Gradle in IntetlliJ

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, intellij-idea, amazon-polly

I am trying to setup AWS Polly Java SDK with Gradle in IntelliJ by following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html). I have already created a simple Spring Boot application using the `spring intializr`, so I added the items specified in the tutorial to my `build.gradle` file. When try to import

> `import com.amazonaws.services.polly.AmazonPollyClient`

IntelliJ fails to resolve name `polly`.

This is my full `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.3.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'io.ai.vivid'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.228'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Also IntelliJ complains that it can't resolve the name `manvenBom` in my `build.gradle`. I have already tried SO solutions to this like invalidate cache/restart but could not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your `build.gradle` file to replicate the issue and was able to import `AmazonPollyClient` after making the following changes to the `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-polly', version: '1.11.67'
```

The Gradle version used 4.8